# How to PushAsync from MasterPage?

Tags: xamarin, mvvm

I have MasterPage that currently using Event-Driven approach as follow:

**MasterPage.xaml.cs**

```
private void TapHome_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Detail = new NavigationPage(new HomePage());
        IsPresented = false;
    }
```

**App.xaml.cs:**

```
public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Preferences.Get(Constant.Setting_AccessToken, "")))
        {
            MainPage = new MasterPage();
        }
        else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Preferences.Get(Constant.Setting_UserEmail, "")) && 
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(Preferences.Get(Constant.Setting_Password, "")))
        {
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());
        }

    }
```

Since we tried to migrate to the MVVM approach. We attempted to change the code:

**MasterPage.xaml.cs**

```
public MasterPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = _viewModel = new MasterViewModel()
        {
            Navigation = Navigation
        };
        //IsPresented = false;
    }
```

**MasterViewModel.cs:**

```
public ICommand HomeCommand { get; private set; }

    public ICommand ActivitiesCommand { get; private set; }

    public ICommand ChangePasswordCommand { get; private set; }

    public ICommand LogoutCommand { get; private set; }

    public MasterViewModel()
    {
        HomeCommand = new Command(async () => await GoToHome());
        ActivitiesCommand = new Command(async () => await GoToActivities());
        ChangePasswordCommand = new Command(async () => await GoToChangePassword());
        LogoutCommand = new Command(async () => await Logout());
    }

    public async Task GoToHome()
    {
        // Attempt 1:
        // Navigation.PushAsync(new NavigationPage(new HomePage()));

        // Attempt 2:
        // Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new HomePage());
    }
```

Tried the first attempt and we have error on Android - *System.InvalidOperationException: PushAsync is not supported globally on Android, please use a NavigationPage.*

Tried the second attempt and worked OK but no navigation at HomePage or other pages after clicking it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind. We worked out this:

```
public async Task GoToHome()
    {
        ((MasterDetailPage)Application.Current.MainPage).Detail = new NavigationPage(new HomePage());
        ((MasterDetailPage)Application.Current.MainPage).IsPresented = false;
    }
```

Comment: @dcpartnrts, Glad to hear that you solved your issue, please remember to mark your reply as answer, thanks.